# What is the equivalent of on prem ha dr solutions in the azure cloud PaaS and SaaS?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, high-availability, disaster-recovery, azure-sql-managed-instance

On prem ha dr solutions are:

1. Log shipping
2. Mirroring
3. Replication
4. FCI
5. AG

What is the equivalent of each of the above in the azure cloud PaaS  (azure sql managed instance) and SaaS (azure sql database)?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the equivalent of each of the above in the azure cloud PaaS

There aren't equivalents.  Azure SQL PaaS has built-in HA and DR, with a few optional additions.  But it's all managed by the service without you having to plan and implement solutions similar to what you would use with on-prem or IaaS SQL Server.

Read: [High availability for Azure SQL Database and SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/high-availability-sla)